# How to writing files with expl3

Tags: expl3

I'm start to study expl3 but it's so difficult for me.

I'm trying to understand how file management works.

How can to fix my next mwe for don't ignore the lines break at the first call to \Write command, and the last call to \Write append the full expanded content to the file?

Thanks for your help!

````
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\iow_new:N \tdm_io
\iow_open:Nn \tdm_io {testfile1.txt}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Write}{+m}{
\iow_now:Nx \tdm_io {#1}
}
\Write{aaa

aa}
\Write{bbbbb}
\Write{ccccc}
\iow_close:N \tdm_io
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\def\cmd{Content command}

\Write{Append the \cmd at the end of file}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: You're looking for \iow_newline or something like that. (read its doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing the first lines inside the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn`, where blank spaces and blank lines are ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \g_rodriguez_tdm_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_rodriguez_tdm_iow {\jobname.txt}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Write}{+m}
  {
    \iow_now:Nx \g_rodriguez_tdm_iow {#1}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\Write{aaa

aa}
\Write{bbbbb}
\Write{ccccc}

\begin{document}

\def\cmd{Content command}

\Write{Append the \cmd\space at the end of file}

\end{document}
```

Please, use the correct format for names of variables. The written out file will contain

```
aaa \par aa
bbbbb
ccccc
Append the Content command at the end of file
```

as expected.